# Play HLS live stream from start

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I have an event type m3u8 playlist, which I'm playing using AVPlayer. It all works perfectly fine except seeking to past times in stream. When paused I can seek to any time I want to and I see correct updated frame in player, however anytime I tap on play it goes back to last ~10 seconds of stream and plays from there.

That's playlist I'm using, I tested it using JWPlayer HLS test and it works good.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:4
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:EVENT
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:2.000,
0.ts
#EXTINF:2.000,
1.ts
#EXTINF:2.000,
2.ts
#EXTINF:2.000,
3.ts
#EXTINF:2.000,
...
```

Code I'm using to rewind:

```
func seek(to time: TimeInterval, play: Bool = false) {
    guard let currentItem = avPlayer.currentItem else { return }
    if avPlayer.status != .readyToPlay || currentItem.status != .readyToPlay { return }

    let time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(time, currentItem.currentTime().timescale)

    if time != chaseTime {
        avPlayer.pause()

        chaseTime = time
        if !seekInProgress {
            actuallySeekToTime(play: play)
        }
    }
}

private func actuallySeekToTime(play: Bool) {
    seekInProgress = true
    let seekTimeInProgress = chaseTime!
    avPlayer.seek(to: seekTimeInProgress, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero) { [weak self] finished in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

        if seekTimeInProgress == strongSelf.chaseTime {
            strongSelf.seekInProgress = false
            if play {
                strongSelf.avPlayer.play()
            }
        } else {
            strongSelf.actuallySeekToTime(play: play)
        }
    }
}
```